# How to integrate floating numbers into a java server calculator?

Tags: java, math, client, calculator, server

I am very very new in Java and Stackoverflow also. So, I found this code in Stackoverflow. Only changed some calculations. Sorry for all inconveniences.

This server can add, sub, multiply, divide 2 integer numbers. It also can calculate the sine, tangent and cosine of an integer.

For example, if you want to add 2 and 3, just type "ADD 2 3" to the console on the client side.
If you want to find cosine of 1, type "COS 1" to the console.

I need an answer until tomorrow.

My question is:

1- How to calculate more than 2 elements? Number of the elements are unknown until pressing the enter button.

2- How to calculate the floating numbers? It terminates server and client if you want to calculate the floating elements.

3- Whenever client connects the server will respond to the client as "welcome" and the client will respond as "hi". How to make this possible?

The code is

Server side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server 
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        ServerSocket opensocket = new ServerSocket(5010); //put server online
        while(true)  
        { 
            System.out.println("Waiting to accept connection");
            Socket clientSock = opensocket.accept();  //open server to connections
            System.out.println("Connection accepted");
            process(clientSock);                    //process accepted connection
            System.out.println("Connection closed");
        } 
    }  

    //BufferedReader(Reader r)
    static void process(Socket sock) throws IOException 
    {  
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream(); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream(); 
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);       

        String input = br.readLine(); //get user input from client                

        while(input != null && !input.equals("bye")) //check for input, if bye exit connection
        {              
            float answer = operate(input); //perform desired operation on user input
            pw.println(answer);          //print out result
            //pw.println("answer");          //print out result
            input = br.readLine();       //get next line of input  
        } 
        sock.close(); 
    }  

    //Talk to the client          
    static float operate(String s) 
    { 
        System.out.println(s); //check if same as client input

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(s); 
        String opType = myScanner.next();   //gets desired operation

        System.out.println(opType); //checks for correct operation 
        switch (opType) { 
            case "ADD": 
                return (myScanner.nextFloat() + myScanner.nextFloat());
            case "SUB":
                return (myScanner.nextInt() - myScanner.nextInt());
            case "MUL":
                return (myScanner.nextInt() * myScanner.nextInt());
            case "DIV":
                return myScanner.nextInt() / myScanner.nextInt();
            case "COS":
                return (float) Math.cos(myScanner.nextInt());
            case "SIN":
                return (float) Math.sin(myScanner.nextInt());
            case "TAN":
                return (float) Math.tan(myScanner.nextInt());
            default:
                return (0);

        }        
    }
}
```

Client side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client
{


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
     Socket Sock = new Socket("LocalHost", 5010);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Sock.getInputStream()));
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Sock.getOutputStream(), true);


     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     String input;


     while(true)
     {
     System.out.println("Please enter your function and numbers:");
        input = sc.nextLine();

        pw.println(input);

        if(input.equals("disconnect"))
        {
           System.out.println("disconnected from the server");
           break;

        }


        System.out.println(br.readLine());
     }

     Sock.close();

  }


}
```

Comment: to question one you could go  in say one of the cases float f=nextfloat;while(!howeveryouwanttoprovetheuserisdone){f+=nextfloat;}your third question seems basic so i think i dont really get the question just print back welcom and in a while loop check the scanner.next for the hi

Answer (score 0):

For #1, use a loop and some data structure. ArrayList is fine for this. When you pull the line in, split it using whatever delimiter you're using, such as a space. Pull out the first String for your op type, just as you did, but then add all the remaining parts to the list as the type you want them. Then perform the operation on all elements of your list using a loop and return it. For example:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(s);
String opType = s.next();

List numbers = new ArrayList();
while( s.hasNextFloat() )
{
    numbers.add( s.nextFloat() ) // or whatever type you want
}
```

That stores any number of elements passed in beside the operation. You can now perform the desired operation on however many elements there are in the list:

```
float result = 0;
for(float f : numbers)
{
    result += f;
}
```

You can do this inside a method for each operation type so that you preserve your switch structure doesn't become cluttered.